# add additional fields while maintaining input content

Tags: javascript, html, forms, textarea

I'm trying to make an input form with multiple fields and generate a preview of this content in a div. I would like the user to be able to add additional fields as they wish. I have the basic functionality working but anytime I "add" an additional field, the entered content of my previous fields are wiped out. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated. I've included the relevant code below.

```
    function addInput(){
        var inpts = document.getElementById("inputs");
        var inputCounter = Number(document.getElementById("inputCounter").innerHTML);
        var incCount = inputCounter+1;
        var currentInfo = inpts.innerHTML;
        var newField = "<textarea id=\"" + incCount + "\" rows=\"2\" onblur=\"updatePreview()\"></textarea> <div onclick=\"addInput()\" style=\"display: inline-block;\">+</div><br />";

        inpts.innerHTML = currentInfo + newField;
        document.getElementById("inputCounter").innerHTML = incCount;
    }
```

The call to the function looks like this...

```
    <div style="display: none;" id="inputCounter">1</div>
    <div id='inputs'>
            <textarea id='1' rows="2" onblur="updatePreview()"></textarea> <div onclick="addInput()" style="display: inline-block;">XX</div><br />
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`innerHTML` returns the HTML structure but it excludes the value property of form elements (such as `textarea`).

Instead, you could create a new element to hold the additional field, then append that element to `inputs`:

```
function addInput(){
  var inpts = document.getElementById("inputs"),
      inputCounter = Number(document.getElementById("inputCounter").innerHTML),
      incCount = inputCounter+1,
      div = document.createElement('div');

  div.innerHTML= "<textarea id=\"" + incCount + "\" rows=\"2\" onblur=\"updatePreview()\"></textarea> <div onclick=\"addInput()\" style=\"display: inline-block;\">+</div><br />";
  inpts.appendChild(div);
  document.getElementById("inputCounter").innerHTML = incCount;
} //addInput
```

[**Working Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/3jy18z7u/)

---

An alternative to creating a new element is to use [**`insertAdjacentHTML`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML):

```
function addInput(){
  var inpts = document.getElementById("inputs"),
      inputCounter = Number(document.getElementById("inputCounter").innerHTML),
      incCount = inputCounter+1;

  inpts.insertAdjacentHTML(
    'beforeend',
    "<textarea id=\"" + incCount + "\" rows=\"2\" onblur=\"updatePreview()\"></textarea> <div onclick=\"addInput()\" style=\"display: inline-block;\">+</div><br />"
  );

  document.getElementById("inputCounter").innerHTML = incCount;

} //addInput
```

[**Working Fiddle #2**](http://jsfiddle.net/vxb94cn7/)

Comment: Your solution does what I want, but I'm not sure I understand why it works differently. Can you explain a little?

Comment: I've updated my response, plus I added an alternative method that's probably better.